# Append won't add a Arraylike to an array

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently doing a project, and need to use CSV files to display information
That part is figured out, but it won't allow me to append it with a known array

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import glob

path = "/Users/kagemanden/Downloads/CSV Datapunkter"
csv_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
x = np.array([])

for i in csv_files:
    print(i)
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, i))
    g=np.array([len(df)])
    print(g)
    np.append(x,g)
print(x)
plt.bar(np.arange(len(x))+1,x)
plt.show()
```

It is the append function that doesn't work, the rest works just fine

Basically all i know, but the Append function is an integral funcction, and i don't know how to build the code without it

Comment: When you try to use a numpy function (even if it is "integral"?), take time to actually read and understand its documentation - especially if your first try doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.append` returns a copy of the array, but do not modify the array itself. So `np.append(x,g)` does what you want, but you never save the result of this operation.

What you want to do is `x = np.append(x, g)`. This way, the result of `np.append` is stored in `x`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import glob

path = "/Users/kagemanden/Downloads/CSV Datapunkter"
csv_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
x = np.array([])

for i in csv_files:
    print(i)
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, i))
    g=np.array([len(df)])
    print(g)
    x = np.append(x,g)
print(x)
plt.bar(np.arange(len(x))+1,x)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to imitate a list method with arrays.  `np.append` is NOT a list append clone!  Even when it works it is slower.

```
x = []
for i in csv_files:
    print(i)
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, i))
    x.append(len(df))
```

or simply

```
x = [len(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,i)) for i in csv_files]
```